# Found nil in NSDateFormatter function

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So what my code does is that it takes the NSDate from UIDaterPicker (timePicker) and changes the time zone. After that it is converted back to an NSDate to start a NSTimer.

But it crashes inside the convertToDate function. Apparently it seems that I'm trying to force unwrap a optional. But why is it a optional?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

        func convertTime() -> String {
            let date = timePicker.date
            print("date", date)
            let myTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
            let df = NSDateFormatter()
            df.timeZone = myTimeZone
            df.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"
            let time = df.stringFromDate(date)

            return time
        }

        func convertToDate() -> NSDate {
            let date = convertTime()
            let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
            let convertedTime = dateformatter.dateFromString(date)

            return convertedTime!
        }

func fireTime() -> NSDate {
        let time = convertToDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*2.4)
        return time
    }

    func updateTimeLeft() {
        let elapsedTime = fireTime().timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())
        self.ringTime.text = NSDateComponentsFormatter().stringFromTimeInterval(elapsedTime)
    }

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimeLeft), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: `NSDate` does not have a time zone to change.

Comment: Word of warning from an architecture perspective: It's better to make your small helper functions such as `convertToDate()`, `fireTime()` use parameters for their input data, rather than directly accessing object fields. This makes these functions easily testable in isolation.

Comment: Do you know about optionals? Do you know what you are actually doing with `return convertedTime!`? Have you googled the docs?

Comment: I wonder why you convert timePicker.date to a String and back to NSDate. And why do you add 60*60*2.4 ? What problem are you trying to solve with all these conversions?

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` returns an optional because not every string represents a valid date. The optionality allows for an elegant for it to reply "This isn't a valid data according to the format you told me to use".

```
    func convertToDate() -> NSDate {
        let date = convertTime()
        let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter .dateFormat = "INSERT DATE FORMAT HERE"

        if let convertedTime = dateformatter.dateFromString(date) {
            return convertedTime
        }
        else {
            //formatting failed. Handle the error here
        }
    }
```

You haven't given a format string for it to use, so it doesn't know how to parse your date, thus it returns nil.

If you post an example of your data, I'll show you the format string you need.

Comment: which data do you mean?

Comment: The `date` you're trying to parse

Comment: It is the value from UIDatePicker and I want to display the remaining time until this date is met in the ringTime Label.

Comment: Yes, now give me an example of the contents of that date when it crashes.

Comment: unexpectedly found nil. EXC_BreakPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1002ba588).  0x1002ba588 <+44>:  brk    #0x1

Comment: ... Give me an example of the content of the "date" variable, at the time of the crash

Comment: I get this right before the crash: 2016.06.01 n. Chr. at 20:59:35 MESZ

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what i'm saying.

Comment: You are trying to parse the variable, called `date`. What is the `date` your trying to parse? What is the **VALUE** of the **DATE** variable from the UIDatePicker immediately prior to the crash?

Comment: Why do you get the date (as NSDate) in `convertTime()`, convert it to a `String`, only to convert it back in `convertToDate()`? That makes no sense.

Comment: Because this is the only way to change the time zone.

Comment: I get the UTC time which is pickerdate 2016-06-01 19:11:23 +0000 as soon after it is a string it is: date 2016.06.01 n. Chr. at 21:12:23 MESZ. If print convertedTime it returns nil.

Comment: So you'll need to create a format string that matches that format. See this documentation, and check out the link to "Data Formatting Guide": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/dateFormat